# Are ArcMap Addins compatible with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, compatibility

In other words, can ArcGIS Pro load an ArcMap AddIn?

Comment: An answer on the duplicate says "Add-Ins based on the ArcObjects APIs will not work in Pro".

Comment: The question itself isn't a duplicate (and I would argue that `Creating AddIns for ArcGIS Pro?` is a poor quality question for this site). The answer happens to be duplicated with this question, but it is not easily discoverable in google searches. (FWIW, I knew the answer but knew of other non-programmers who were unable to google an answer as no gis.se questions show up in the first page).

Comment: @JayCummins I agree the two questions don't ask quite the same thing, however the answer there definitely answers your question.

Comment: One of the ways that someone *might* try to create an AddIn to ArcGIS Pro, is by doing it as an ArcMap AddIn to plug into ArcGIS Pro.  The duplicate Q&A warns that this simply will not work.  This question is phrased differently, and both are very brief, but I see them as "two faces of the same coin".

Comment: Maybe if you are a developer.  But non-GIS developers use this site too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The use of add ins in ArcGIS Pro is described in [ArcGIS Pro Extensibility with Add-Ins](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/02/13/arcgis-pro-extensibility-with-add-ins/)